# QT Timer (Start/ Pause)

Tags: c, qt, timer

I am trying to implement a timer in Qt and I have a Start/ pause (single button) and a reset button. When I click the start button, it starts the timer and the text on the button changes to pause and when I click the pause again the text changes back to start and the time XX:XX:XX is paused, but when I click the start again the timer goes back to 00:00:00 (It clears the timer and starts the count from start). I do not know what is happening and how I could stop this.

On the other hand reset button seems to have been work fine.

I've tried correcting it and the only working way I found was when I include  `now = time(NULL);` when the button is pressed the timer starts with 00:00:00. Or else it keeps the time of the systemtimer and starts with a random number.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Apologies for the any inconvenience.

```
IncDisplay::IncDisplay(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IncDisplay),
    running(false),
    elapsed(0), s(0), m(0), h(0)
{

    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateDisplay()));
    time(&now);
    timer.start(10);
    ui->timer->display("00:00:00");
    updateDisplay();
}

IncDisplay::~IncDisplay()
{
    delete ui;
}

void IncDisplay::updateDisplay()
{
    QTime timex = QTime::currentTime();
    QString text = timex.toString("hh:mm");

    ui->clock->display(text);

    if (running) {
        double sec = difftime(time(NULL), now);
        s = (int)sec % 60;
        m = (int)(sec / 60) % 60;
        h = (int)(sec / 3600) % 60;


        QString text = QString().sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s);
        ui->timer->display(text);
    }
}

void IncDisplay::on_start_clicked()
{
    running = !running;

    if (running) {
        now = time(NULL);
        ui->start->setText("Pause");
    }
    else {
        ui->start->setText("Start");
    }
}

void IncDisplay::on_reset_clicked()
{
    running = false;
    elapsed = 0;
    ui->start->setText("Start");
    ui->timer->display("00:00:00");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pause and resume a Qtimer (Qt 5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440727/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-qtimer-qt-5)

Comment: @SamuraiJack [Please don't abuse `code formatting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep a `QTime` object with elapsed time:

```
IncDisplay::IncDisplay(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::IncDisplay),
    elapsed(0, 0, 0), // a QTime object
    interval(10) // an interger containing timer interval
{
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout()));
    timer.start(interval);
    updateDisplay();
}

void IncDisplay::onTimeout()
{
    elapsed = elapsed.addMSecs(timer.interval());
    updateDisplay();
}

void IncDisplay::updateDisplay()
{
    ui->timer->display(elapsed.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
}

void IncDisplay::on_start_clicked()
{
    if (timer.isRunning())
    {
        timer.stop();
        ui->start->setText("Start");
    }
    else
    {
        timer.start(interval);
        ui->start->setText("Pause");        
    }
}

void IncDisplay::on_reset_clicked()
{
    timer.stop();
    ui->start->setText("Start");
    elapsed = QTime(0, 0, 0);
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hank, 
But when I compile the program I get 8 errors because of the "interval"

C:\Users\\Desktop\Softwares\New folder\Inc-display\Incdisplay.cpp:12: error: class 'IncDisplay' does not have any field named 'interval'
     interval(10)
     ^

Comment: @HenryKissinger Obviously you will have to declare a variable before you can use it. It's probably meant to be in the private section of the class declaration in the header file.