# How can I implement a pausable/resumable timer in C++ with QT that preserves the remaining time when paused and continues from where it left off?

Tags: qt

I'm working on a project in C++ with QT, and I need to create a timer that can be paused and resumed while preserving the remaining time when paused. For example, if the timer has a 1000ms interval and I pause it with 500ms remaining, I want it to trigger a timeout signal after 500ms and then resume with the next trigger occurring after 1000ms. How can I achieve this functionality?

I attempted to implement the pausable/resumable timer using the stop and start methods as follows:

```
QTimer* timer;
void togglePlay() {
    if (timer->isActive()) {
        timer->stop();
    }
    else {
        timer->start(_interval);
    }
}
```

However, after calling start, the remainingTime becomes the same as interval, rather than preserving the previous remaining time.

I also tried saving the remainingTime and setting it when restarting the timer, like this:

```
QTimer* timer;
int remainingTime = -1;
void togglePlay() {
    if (timer->isActive()) {
        remainingTime = timer->remainingTime();
        timer->stop();
    }
    else {
        if (remainingTime == -1){
            timer->start(_interval);
        }
        else {
            timer->start(remainingTime);
        }
    }
}
```

However, after calling start, the timer's interval becomes remainingTime, instead of interval.

Comment: Maybe this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440727/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-qtimer-qt-5 could help you ?

Comment: @ElevenJune Thank you, I think it may not work. My requirement is to trigger the status update every time, not for timing.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be to use the `setInterval(int msec)` method of the QTimer class.

Example:

```
QTimer* timer;
int remainingTime = -1;
void togglePlay() {
    if (timer->isActive()) {
        remainingTime = timer->remainingTime();
        timer->stop();
    }
    else {
        if (remainingTime == -1){
            timer->start(_interval);
        }
        else {
            timer->setInterval(remainingTime); // <- change to this
        }
    }
}
```

Then when the signal is emitted, in the slot you can resume the previous duration of the timer if needed.

Docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html#interval-prop

Comment: Yes, it works, and 'timer->start(remainingTime)' can also achieve the desired behavior. However, it requires resetting the interval back to its original value after each timeout signal, which could result in a performance overhead, especially if the timer is called frequently. This is why I was looking for a more efficient solution that avoids having to check and reset the interval with every timeout signal.